# Exec bad access for a variable which is instantiated

Tags: ios, objective-c

I initialize a variable (userMarkerLayer) in `viewDidLoad`. When I use it in that method access is ok. but I set a button and I want to access to it when that button tapped.

```
 @implementation MapViewController
 {
     NTVectorElementLayer *userMarkerLayer;
 }

 (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    userMarkerLayer = [NTNeshanServices createVectorElementLayer];
    [userMarkerLayer addMarker: marker]; // This is ok
  }


-(IBAction)showList:(id)sender {
   [userMarkerLayer addMarker: marker];
   // error: 
   // Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x150543c30)
}


cannot access the userMarkerLayer!
```

**When I enable ARC, this problem not happens. but I have to set it no.**

Comment: Please, read how to provide [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). This is not enough. It doesn't show how the `userMarkerLayer` is stored, what `marker` is, how it is created, what you do with them during view controller life time, ... Create a MRE & update your question.

Comment: @zrzka Thanks. I updated the question. marker is not important because the access error is for userMarkerLayer.

Comment: Shouldn't you replace ```userMarkerLayer``` with ```self.userMarkerLayer```? You are setting a local variable in ```viewDidLoad``` which goes out of scope as soon as the method is done.

Comment: @skaak nope, `userMarkerLayer` is ivar and you can use in this way. This isn't a local variable. P.S. And it's by default `__strong`.

Comment: @FattanehTalebi I'm sorry, but this isn't still enough info. How does the stacktrace look like? What is `marker`? How is it stored? It's not MRE and it isn't even compilable (missing `-` before `(void)`), ... I mean, with the info you provided, it's a guessing game.

Comment: @FattanehTalebi MRC then ... Update your code with `userMarkerLayer = [[NTNeshanServices createVectorElementLayer] retain]` and add `dealloc` where you have to release it with `[userMarkerLayer release]`. Or declare a property (`@property (nonatomic, retain) NTVectorElementLayer *userMarkerLayer` and use `self.userMarkerLayer` instead of just `userMarkerLayer`.

Comment: Just curious, why do you have to disable ARC? Do you know that the ARC is a compile time feature and that you can mix MRC & ARC code in your project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using MRC (ARC disabled), please, read [Memory Management Policy](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmRules.html).

In your code, you have an ivar (instance variable) ...

```
@implementation MapViewController {
    NTVectorElementLayer *userMarkerLayer;
}
```

... and you're assigning an object to it ...

```
userMarkerLayer = [NTNeshanServices createVectorElementLayer];
```

... but the problem here is that you do not own this object (no `alloc`, `new`, `copy` or `mutableCopy` in the `createVectorElementLayer` method name).

It means that you're storing a reference to this object, but this object can go away anytime. You have to use `retain` to take an ownership of this object.

To fix this, take an ownership ...

```
userMarkerLayer = [[NTNeshanServices createVectorElementLayer] retain];
```

... and add `dealloc` method ...

```
- (void)dealloc {
    [userMarkerLayer release];
    [super dealloc];
}
```

Or declare it as a property with `retain` ...

```
@interface MapViewController ()

@property (nonatomic, retain) NTVectorElementLayer *userMarkerLayer;

@end
```

... and use `self.userMarkerLayer` instead of just `userMarkerLayer` ...

```
self.userMarkerLayer = [NTNeshanServices createVectorElementLayer];
```

Comment: FWIW I'd suggest the *last* approach where you use a *property* and *self*